# How to prevent user to enter a special character in text box?

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to prevent one particular character `*` (asterisk) from being entered or pasted into a text box.

I tried:

1. `key_press` event - but it does not handle the case when user pastes an asterisk to the text box.
2. `text_changed` event - but when I remove the character, the cursor position goes back to the beginning of the text.

So I am wondering how to handle it, preferably in one event.

Comment: Have you considered permitting asterisks and removing them on submit?

Comment: no actually... whatever i am trying to do is the requirement of the software..

Comment: What do those requirements say about pasting text with a * using Ctrl+V?  Use the Validating event.

Comment: Hi Hans: Instead of removing it in the end from all the textboxes (35), user should know that * is not allowed. +no message box coz of hinderence in work flow..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use the text changed event, but save the location of the cursor (the SelectionStart and SelectionEnd properties) before you remove the asterisk, then re set the cursor position (less the number of asterisks removed before the cursor).

```
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var currentText = textBox1.Text;
        var selectionStart = textBox1.SelectionStart;
        var selectionLength = textBox1.SelectionLength;

        int nextAsterisk;
        while ((nextAsterisk = currentText.IndexOf('*')) != -1)
        {
            if (nextAsterisk < selectionStart)
            {
                selectionStart--;
            }
            else if (nextAsterisk < selectionStart + selectionLength)
            {
                selectionLength--;
            }

            currentText = currentText.Remove(nextAsterisk, 1);
        }

        if (textBox1.Text != currentText)
        {
            textBox1.Text = currentText;
            textBox1.SelectionStart = selectionStart;
            textBox1.SelectionLength = selectionLength;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The updated code in my answer below is working perfectly. But yours code is more clear. I gonna use yours :). Thanks McKay..

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159749/winforms-maskedtextbox-to-accept-certain-chars) may be of use to you. What you're looking for seems like either a MaskedTextBox or a TextBox with custom Validation logic. You should not simply erase an asterisk characters when it is input, because if a user has selected text, then typed an asterisk, they will have replaced the selected text with an asterisk before you have the chance to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the cursor postion. For example:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
```

**EDIT:**

Ok i took some time to write you a solution that works quite good. It keeps the edit cursor at the proper position and also covers the situation in which user pastes some * chars between chars.

```
        int position = this.textBox1.SelectionStart;
        string str = this.textBox1.Text;
        int hit = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < position; i++)
        {
            if (str[i].Equals('*'))
                hit++;

        }
        str = str.Replace("*", "");
        this.textBox1.Text = str;
        this.textBox1.SelectionLength = 0;
        this.textBox1.SelectionStart = position - hit;
```

Comment: this selects the text...but i want cursor in the end of the text so that user can continue writing...

Comment: or remember current position and set it after removing *

Comment: What he is saying is that if you put the beginning of the selection at the end of the text, you're basically setting the cursor position. But beware, because if they type in asterisks in the middle of the word, it will move the cursor to the end.

Comment: Yeah, @arie basically said what my answer says below.

Comment: msdn says: "If no text is selected in the control, this property indicates the insertion point, or caret, for new text." to assure there is no text selected you can set SelectionLength=0;

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution i found:-

On Text_changed event, here is what i am doing:-

```
txt1.Text = txt1.Text.Replace("*", string.Empty);
txt1.Select(txt1.Text.Length, 0);
```

**Updated code:-**
On Text_changed event:-

```
int curpos = 0;
        bool isReplaced = false;
        private void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (txt1.Text.Contains('*'))
            {
                curpos = txt1.SelectionStart;
                isReplaced = true;
            }
            txt1.Text = txt1.Text.Replace("*", string.Empty);
            if (isReplaced)
            {
                txt1.Select(curpos.Equals(0) ? 0 : curpos -1, 0);
                isReplaced = false;
            }
        }
```

**Final code and Tested :-**

```
 if (txt1.Text.Contains('*'))
            {
                foreach (char c in txt1.Text)
                    if (c.Equals('*'))
                        barredCharCount += 1;
                curPosition = txt1.SelectionStart;
                isTextReplaced = true;
            }
            txt1.Text = txt1.Text.Replace("*", string.Empty);
            if (isTextReplaced)
            {
                txt1.Select(curPosition.Equals(0) ? 0 : curPosition - barredCharCount, 0);
                isTextReplaced = false;
                curPosition = barredCharCount = 0;
                Console.Beep(); //does not work on 64 bit system
            }
```

This piece of code is tested and working perfectly...

Comment: This has the same problem that neurotix's solution has, namely, that if they're editing text in the middle of the box, this will move their cursor to the end of the box.

Comment: don't make the curpos, and the isReplaced class variables, make it scoped to the method. This will reduce double update race conditions.

Comment: This will not work for strings like "this*is*a*test" it will probably make your code crash.

Comment: Really, you should look at the answer I supplied up above.